# Convert JSON to Java Object using Jackson Framework

Tags: json, jackson

I am new to Jackson framework and stuck at some point. I am trying to convert JSON message to Java object, however I am getting below error. Could you please advise course of action to fix the issue.

**Error:**

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "coord"
```

the code

```
@Test
    public void jsonToJava(){

        String responseString = "{  \n" +
                "   \"coord\":{  \n" +
                "      \"lon\":21.01,\n" +
                "      \"lat\":52.23\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            Coord cor = mapper.readValue(responseString, Coord.class);
            System.out.println(cor);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

GetterAndSetter Class:

```
public class Coord {

    private Double lon;
    private Double lat;

    public Double getLon() {
        return this.lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return this.lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lon) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be right a json string for your class

```
String responseString = "{\"lon\":21.01,\"lat\":52.23}";
```

Please also correct your setLon method, replace with below

```
public void setLat(Double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways, here are two ways.

In the first way, you can tell to `ObjectMapper` to unwrap root values:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

and change your `Coord` class to something like this:

```
@JsonRootName("coord")
public class Coord {

    private Double lon;
    private Double lat;

    // getters and setters

}
```

To use `@JsonRootName` you'll need [`jackson-annotations`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations). If you're using maven, just add this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're using gradle, add this:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
```

Or download from [wiki](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki) or from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.5.3)

Second way, change your JSON to look like this:

```
{
  "lon":21.01,
  "lat":52.23
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno. Could you please advise, which jar package to use as I am unable to resolve the method for mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); And I have download Annontation jar file as suggested, however still not able to resolve the method

Comment: @user3463885 `DeserializationFeature` is in same package of `ObjectMapper`, whick is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`. Here I'm using jackson version `2.5.0`, both classes are in `jackson-databind` jar.

Comment: @user3463885, what do you need a root element? why do you need an extra annotation when your problem is solved simply fixing your JSON?

Comment: @vzamanillo Indeed, the ways in the response are just to he choose.

Comment: Indeed, that's my intention, a good choosing. Simplify his code.

Comment: Even worse what if you don't have control over the JSON in the input and don't want an additional root element?